# Mapbox zoom to active data

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm new to javascript and I've the following mapbox image. The radiobutton filters the heatmap.

[image]

When the filter happens, I'd want the map to be zoomed in to the center of heatmap and not remain static. The code is below:

```
    <script>

map.on('load', function() {
    d3.json('onlinejsonconvert.geojson', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    map.addSource('tortoise', { type: 'geojson', data: data });
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "tortoise",
        "type": "heatmap",
        "source": "tortoise",
        "maxzoom": 22,
        "paint": {
        }
    }, 'terrain');

  document.getElementById('filters').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var name = e.target.value;

  if (name === 'all') {
    filterDay = ['!=', ['string', ['get', 'individual-local-identifier']], 'placeholder'];
  } else if (name === 'Sparkey') {
    filterDay = ['match', ['get', 'individual-local-identifier'], ['Sparkey'], true, false];
  } else if (name === 'Charles') {
    filterDay = ['match', ['get', 'individual-local-identifier'], ['Charles'], true, false];
  } else if (name === 'Chrissie') {
    filterDay = ['match', ['get', 'individual-local-identifier'], ['Chrissie'], true, false];
  } else if (name === 'Karlitos') {
    filterDay = ['match', ['get', 'individual-local-identifier'], ['Karlitos'], true, false];
  } else if (name === 'Connor') {
    filterDay = ['match', ['get', 'individual-local-identifier'], ['Connor'], true, false];
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }

  map.setFilter('tortoise', ['all', filterDay,]);
});


});
});
</script>
```

I've tried all possible methods. Any leads/solution would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must filter the data objects and keep only the elements that match the filter. For example the ones that `Connor` attribute `== true`.

Then you have those elements, that are the active data that will show up on your map. You must build a bound with them (`activeDataBounds`) and and use `map.fitBounds(activeDataBounds)` to center the map where you want it.

Take a look here to see how to create the bounds from your active data https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglatbounds

You must iterate over the `activeData` array and use `LngLatBounds` `extend` method to construct the desired bounds.